# How to show the time of multiple time zones in Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, clock, time-zone

[This article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-multiple-time-zone-clocks-windows-10) describes how to get the clocks of multiple time zones in the Windows 10 start menu, as follows:

> 1. Open the Alarms & Clock app.
> 2. Click on World Clock.
> 3. On the bottom-right, click the "+" button.
> 4. On the top-left, you'll see a search box, type the location you want to see its time, and click the result to added to the map to complete the task.
>
> [...]
>
> Right-click the time zone in the map, select Pin to Start, and voilà now you have multiple time zones at your fingertips.

However, the screenshot is different from what I see on my machine(s). Specifically, where the article shows the time and day of each time zone, **there is no information within the widgets in my start menu**.

[image: three clock links without any useful information]

I tried changing the size and location of the links to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure `live tiles` are turned on?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf live tiles are turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and these are the steps I followed to fix it:

1. Go to windows settings and select 'Apps'

[image: Apps Settings]

2. Click 'Alarms & Clock' in the list of Apps & features and click 'Advanced options'

[image: Advanced Options]

4. Click 'Reset'

[image: Reset]

5. Remove the existing tiles from the start menu and recreate them in the 'Alarms & Clocks' app

Comment: Looks like it works for me now, even without resetting the app. Although, there is a slight delay when opening the start menu until all clocks are updated and show time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn on live tiles. On the time tile, right-click -> More -> Turn live tile on.

Comment: Live tiles are turned on. Right clicking gives the option to turn live tiles off. Turning them off and then on again didn't help.